# Animation of div doesn't stop after hover event ends

Tags: jquery, css

So, here is my first question from community.

**Question:** I am trying to show a `div` & increase width of hovered `div` with animation.

**Problem:**  I achieved this by *jquery* & *css* but, the problem is on continuous hovering the animation don't stop. So, i want to flush the previous animation from memory once the mouse is out of the div.

*I searched and found something like `stop()` to be used but i am not getting the desired result.*

[Check what i have achieved yet](http://jsfiddle.net/surendraVsingh/fsF3W/1/)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: it think this will use full to you http://jsfiddle.net/fsF3W/4/

Comment: @MMK no its behaving same as i posted. I didn't found it helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, Thanks to everyone for answering & special thanks to @Raminson.

I tried to read & understand `stop()` & finally i figured out what i want

I used `stop(true, false)`

**true** will remove the queued animation.
**false** will not make animation jump to end

And it worked: **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/surendraVsingh/fsF3W/12/)**

**Jquery code:**

```
$('#slider_thumbnail li .slide_thumb').hover(function(e){ 

                 $(this).find('.slide_btn').stop(true, false).animate({width:240});
                 $(this).find('.image-wrapper').stop(true, false).show('slow');
             },function(e){

                 $(this).find('.slide_btn').stop(true, false).animate({width:125});
                 $(this).find('.image-wrapper').stop(true, false).hide('slow');
});​
```

Answer (score 4):

You should use `stop()` before `animate()` method, try the following:

```
$('#slider_thumbnail li .slide_thumb').hover(function(e){
     $(this).find('.slide_btn').stop().animate({width:240});
     $(this).find('.image-wrapper').show('slow');
 },function(e){
     $(this).find('.slide_btn').stop().animate({width:125});
     $(this).find('.image-wrapper').hide('slow');
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/fsF3W/3/)

Comment: It is flickering the animation

Comment: hey! its in better condition now but, as @SJGJ said its flickering & after stopping multiple hover it shows the complete image once & hide. But, thanks for making it better. +1 for u

Comment: @SVS hey, you are welcome, you can use animate function for image too, and specify duration for both of them.

Comment: @Raminson will its make any difference??

Comment: @Raminson Can you make a fiddle for what you are talking about as i am new to Jquery.

Comment: @Raminson thanks! but the animation delay of div's width & image showing is not matching. making the image show after animation ends is not fulfilling my purpose.

Comment: @Raminson I don't you think its not what we are trying to do. check the navigation to slider in this website goo.gl/Y5Yqw

Answer (score 1):

I have used [hoverIntent](http://cherne.net/brian/resources/jquery.hoverIntent.html) plugin for this issue before, it worked very well. maybe you want to try this:

Comment: Thanks! for the answer. I checked this plugin before its good & ya it works too. But, i don't want to use any extra plugin. But this will help others so +1 for this.

Answer (score 0):

I appreciate it isn't what you wanted, but I'm bored and wanted to do it.

Pure CSS version of what (I think) you want: http://jsfiddle.net/fsF3W/5/