# jquery hover not working properly

Tags: jquery, hover

I have the following code and it keeps slidingdown and up when i hover on initially. how can i fix this

http://jsfiddle.net/nimeshrmr/2p783/

Comment: actually i didnt get your question can you elaborate, please

Comment: @Rakhitha Nimesh: See my answer below;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `.stop(true, true)` before `.slideUp()` and `.slideDown()`

[**.stop()**](http://api.jquery.com/stop/) stop the currently-running animation on the matched elements.

```
.stop( [clearQueue] [, jumpToEnd] )
```

**clearQueue:** A Boolean indicating whether to remove queued animation as well. Defaults to false.

**jumpToEnd:** A Boolean indicating whether to complete the current animation immediately. Defaults to false.

[**SEE FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/akhurshid/2p783/4/)

Comment: Looks like this is working properly.Have to check few times. Thanks

Comment: can u explain what exactly happens there

Comment: @A.K thanks! +1 because it solved my question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11700724/animation-of-div-doesnt-stop-after-hover-event-ends/11755235#11755235

Answer (score 0):

According to A.K comment, he advices to use ***.stop(true, true)*** instead of ***.stop()***..

**Updated Post**

Try this add ***stop(true, true)*** before .slideDown() and .slideUp()

```
$(".portfolio-image-3col").on("mouseenter",function(){
   $(this).parent().find(".portfolio-desc-3col").stop(true, true).slideDown("fast");
});

$(".portfolio-desc-3col").on("mouseout",function(){
   $(this).parent().find(".portfolio-desc-3col").stop(true, true).slideUp("fast");
});​
```

**old post.**

Try this add stop() before .slideDown() and .slideUp()

```
$(".portfolio-image-3col").on("mouseenter",function(){
   $(this).parent().find(".portfolio-desc-3col").stop().slideDown("fast");
});

$(".portfolio-desc-3col").on("mouseout",function(){
   $(this).parent().find(".portfolio-desc-3col").stop().slideUp("fast");
});​
```

Comment: By adding only `.stop()` it stuck sometime: see demo: http://jsfiddle.net/akhurshid/2p783/2/ So used `.stop(true, true)` working perfectly: See demo: http://jsfiddle.net/akhurshid/2p783/4/

Answer (score 0):

Start from parent and then find the children http://jsfiddle.net/2p783/5/

```
$(".portfolio-item").hover(function() {
     $(this).find(".portfolio-desc-3col").slideDown("fast");
}, function() {
     $(this).find(".portfolio-desc-3col").slideUp("fast");
});
```

Hope it helps :)

Comment: it should be done on dynamically generated elements using the on function